# How to do programmatically Tap/Touch in React Native?

Tags: android, react-native, touch, touch-event, tap

I have a pop up which is gone once I tap/touch anywhere on the screen. I want to do this programmatically tap/touch so that a human touch is not required.

what i need to add / change in my code?

My application is in React Native.

I have tried several example codes which are available but nothing is working. I am able to tap/touch on a button through programmatically. But what I need is tap/touch with out human interaction.

Comment: can you share which popup lib/package you are using ?

Comment: I have pinned my application and pinned pop-up is coming. This pop up when I am doing a human touch anywhere then it gets hide and complete remove. I just want to remove it programmatically in react native . so that No need to do a human touch .

Comment: is timeout included on your options? maybe you could share the snippet